# The tkinter treeview keeps expanding when switching themes using ttkthemes

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I want to make a program that has a treeview, and also the ability to switch between dark mode and light mode anytime. I am using ttkthemes for the different themes.

i expected the treeview to not expand (just like how the other widgets remained the same size) when the themes are switched.

But, each time you switch themes, the treeview expands a bit. Why does this happen and how do i fix this unexpected result?

I've tried using grid_forget() to forget the treeview and re-grid it again each time the themes are switched, but it still produces the same result. Frames makes no difference. Tried googling but received no results to my problem.

Example of it expanding:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

root = ThemedTk(theme="arc")

myTreeview = ttk.Treeview()
myTreeview.grid(row=0,column=0)

def switchToDark():
    root.configure(theme="equilux")

    #The method i tried
    #myTreeview.grid_forget()
    #myTreeview.grid(row=0,column=0)

darkButton = ttk.Button(text="Dark Mode",command=switchToDark)
darkButton.grid(row=1,column=0)

def switchToLight():
    root.configure(theme="arc")

    #myTreeview.grid_forget()
    #myTreeview.grid(row=0,column=0)

lightButton = ttk.Button(text="Light Mode",command=switchToLight)
lightButton.grid(row=0,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try to open the issue in the [project repository](https://github.com/TkinterEP/ttkthemes).

Comment: @8349697 apparently it is not just ttkthemes, the same issue when using a completely different theme that doesn't use ttkthemes either. Anyway, I've just made my own solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own solution that actually works, if anyone found a different solution, please do share it! (NOTE: this solution currently only works for rows that use numbers as their IIDs)

Firstly, initialise valuesList as a global variable:

```
valuesList = []
```

Next, whenever a row is inserted into the treeview, add this:

```
global valuesList
valuesList.append(myTreeview.item(len(myTreeview.get_children()),option='values'))
```

Basically, `myTreeview.item(len(myTreeview.get_children()),option='values')` gets the tuple of values of each row (excluding the text and IID).

`get_children()` method returns a list of items' IIDs of either the parent or the root.

`len(myTreeview.get_children())+1`, because that is how I set the IIDs for each row (e.g. if `len(myTreeview.get_children()) == 2`, this means the treeview currently has two rows. The IID for the added row would then be 3.

Function for switching themes:

```
def switchToDark():
    root.configure("equilux") # change the theme

    myTreeview.destroy() # destroy and reinitialise the treeview
    myTreeview = ttk.Treeview()
    myTreeview.grid(row=0,column=0)
    # add necessary columns and headings here

    idNumber = len(databaseTree.get_children())
        
        for tupleOfValues in valuesList: # iterate through the list of tuples
            idNumber += 1
            databaseTree.insert(parent='',index='end',iid=idNumber,text=idNumber,values=(tupleOfValues[0],tupleOfValues[1],tupleOfValues[2],tupleOfValues[3],tupleOfValues[4]))
            # the above is reinserting the original values one by one
```

A sample of valuesList at this point would look like:

```
[(value1, value2, value3), (value1, value2, value3)] # a list of tuples
# row 1 values ^              row 2 values ^
```

And so tupleOfValues would be:

```
(value1, value2, value3)
```

Depending on the number of values you have for your treeview, you might need more or less of `tupleOfValues[i]`. Since I have 5 values, I go up to `tupleOfValues[4]`. The same goes for switching to light mode.

I hope this helped!

Comment: As far as I understand, the main idea is to store all the values of the treeview in a global variable at the very beginning, and when changing the theme, completely recreate the entire treeview from scratch.